# The one-way street

Tags: lateral-thinking

A girl who was just learning to drive went down a one-way street in the wrong direction, but didn't break the law.

**How is this possible?**

Comment: This isn't that hard. A single Google search gets me to this riddle's answer.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole Well, the whole idea is to get the solution without doing a Google search!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Umm... How about...

> She was walking?

Answer (score 11):

An alternate solution:

> She was learning to drive an ambulance (or other emergency vehicle), which are permitted to go the wrong way down one-way streets when their lights and sirens are on.

I like this answer a little better because

> when someone is walking down the street, there isn't technically a "wrong direction".

Answer (score 8):

She

> walked down the one-way street

Comment: LoL, 13 seconds.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I love the vote discrepancy, too. Y'all are HARSH

Answer (score 5):

I read this very differently

> She legally went down the one way street, but her intended destination lay in the opposite direction. She was going the wrong way on a one way street.

Comment: Interesting way to think about it.

Answer (score 3):

Here it is: She was driving in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

How about a different answer...

> She was driving a float for a parade, and got a special permit to do so.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>She was driving in the U.S. with a peculiar hood ornament.</strike>

> Alabama with a lantern on the front.

Answer crossed-out, this is an urban legend.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of places on the internet where this is repeated, but no actual citations or evidence that it's true. [Alabama code §32-5A-87](http://codes.lp.findlaw.com/alcode/32/5A/4/32-5A-87) covers one-way roads, and doesn't make any mention of this.

Comment: @f'' Reviewed websites, I'll cite http://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/what-s-the-dumbest-law-still-current-in-your-state-1712980.html.  The lawyer there states the law does not exist and posted in 2014.  I did not find any other citeable evidence.

Answer (score -1):

The street was closed for driving practice.